# correct mysql data type for column that contain multiple index ids

Tags: mysql, sqldatatypes

In my sql I have a table (trades) that contains a list of trades

Each trade has an id.

I have another table (companies) that contains a list of companies, in this table there is a trades column, in here there will be id's for trades, there could be more than one trade.

What is the best data type for the trades column in the companies table?

Sorry if my terminology isn't correct!

Comment: I think `String` should be used and save `ids` with comma separated.

Comment: This is not a good idea. Move that field to a table with id of the company and Id of the trade. You will save a lot of time doing search, update and delete after

Comment: same datatype which you used in trade table

Comment: There is no (good) data type for that. See normalisation

Answer (score 0):

To keep atomarity (modularity) of data items in tables and for flexibility of future SELECT queries (JOINs, GROUPing, searching and etc.) best practice to have table which will have fields that keeps relation of these data items. This will help You to have many-to-many relation.

So here is example:

```
-- Create syntax for TABLE 'companies'
CREATE TABLE `companies` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- Create syntax for TABLE 'trades'
CREATE TABLE `trades` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- Create syntax for TABLE 'companies_trades'
CREATE TABLE `companies_trades` (
  `company_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `trade_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`company_id`,`trade_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```